# How can I filter out random new lines in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a non-standard serial library to read in high speed CAN Bus data. At low speeds I have not observed this problem but at full speed (approximately 125 messages a second) the `RichTextBox` outputs random new lines. It rarely happens, maybe once every 2-3k lines.

Unwanted new line:

[image: two lines of hexadecimal text values, followed by a blank line, and two more lines of hexadecimal text values]

Message ID is incremented by 1 each message so I can see no message loss occurred.

Code for serial `receiveHandler()` method:

```cs
private void receiveHandler(object sender, DataStreamEventArgs e)
{
    string line = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Response);

    //Console.WriteLine("1) The length of '{0}' is {1}", line, line.Length);

    // line.Split attempts to split the string before it is completely written
    //string[] stringValues = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    //int a = Int32.Parse(stringValues[0]);

    //Console.WriteLine("1) The messge count '{0}' is {1}", line, a);
    
    if(line.Length > 63 && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
        richCANBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { richCANBox.AppendText(line); }));
    }

    // Clear messages in buffer after clear button pressed. 
    // TODO: Try waiting for thread to finish before clearing using join
    if (stopMessage)
    {
        richCANBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { richCANBox.Clear(); }));
    }
}
```

Each message length is 64 so I tried filtering out messages shorter than that and used `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` but I still get random lines. I also increased the amount of bytes available before handle call from 0 to 30 to prevent accessing the data before all bytes arrived but that did not help.

```cs
if (readBytes > 30)
{
    OnSerialReceiving(buf);
}
```

I have very little experience with C# and picked `RichTextBox` because it was easy to save the data capture. Any suggestions on how I might filter out the new line or where I could look to chase down this bug?

Full repository: https://github.com/BrandonVP/HyperCAN

Edit: The device transmitting is an ESP32 and when viewing it's output from either Arduino IDE terminal or VS Micro terminal I do not get any random return lines. I am using AX-Fast Serial Library because the standard library was unable to transmit data fast enough. Also, I tried `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` from the comments but it did not help.

Comment: You'll need to track down how the data received is getting corrupted. It seems most likely to be that the device itself is simply transmitting the empty lines. I'll note that .NET has no `DataStreamEventArgs` type, so it seems you're using some non-standard serial-port object, and haven't shared any of those details, making it that much harder to understand the question. Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68229551/edit) so that it includes a proper [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: I will point out, however, that if the string length check didn't remove the lines, then the lines obviously have 64 or more characters. Again, this would be consistent with the device sending you the blank lines, filled out with characters. The `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` check is pointless once you've checked the length is greater than 0. It's possible that `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` would work in your case, depending on what the device is actually sending.

Comment: I'm going to guess there are multiple new line characters (you could look at your data to determine if this is true). You can check your line variable for this (something like:  `line.Split('\n').Length > 1)` and take appropriate action.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "I am using a non-standard serial library" was in the very first sentence and I left a link to the entire repository. The device transmitting is an ESP32 and when viewing it's output from either Arduino IDE terminal or VS Micro terminal I do not get any random return lines. But your right I should probably have included that. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: _"I left a link to the entire repository."_ -- that's completely useless. Stack Overflow questions are _required_ to be entirely self-contained. If you are using a third-party library, you need to at least provide _specific_ details about which one. If it's your own custom library, you are required to post 100% of the relevant code, and nothing more (i.e. you likely will have to simplify the library code for the purpose of the question).

Comment: Send the output also to a file, use a hex editor to inspect the content, see whether you have random `0x0A` / `0x0D` at the end of a line (or anything else unexpected). Since your lines are indexed, it should be simple to determine what's what. Also, try to `BeginInvoke()` using the parent Form as marshaller instead of a Control (assuming, since you're using MethodInvoker, it's a WinForms' RichTextBox. Tag your question accordingly).

Comment: Change `string line = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Response);` to `string line = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Response).Trim();` and see if the newline still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
richCANBox.Text = richCANBox.Text.Replace(" ","");
```